# Magento 2.4.6-p3 product qty greater than salable quantity - cannot fix

Tags: magento2.4.6, qty, salable

So you've heard this one before I'm sure and I've tried to research how to resolve. This is the issue:

- For a number of products the Qty is greater than the Salable Quantity in my v2.4.6-p3 install.

I have tried to undertake a number of checks:

- I have completed reservation list inconsistency check using:
  bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies
- I fixed the inconsistencies by piping the result of the above into:
  bin/magento inventory:reservation:create-compensations
- no further inconsistencies remained

However, I still have products that have the issue as noted at the beginning. For instance - I have a product with Qty 7 and Salable Quantity 0. Others range in difference.

I would really like to know how to set the two to be the same for all products where it is not and they are not currently reserved for an order that has not been shipped. I've looked and cannot find the answer. I'm sure there must be one but I can't seem to locate it! Is there a way I can find out why the difference exists? Should I be looking more closely at reservation lists? If so how?

Any help most appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

---

Does anyone have any advice on this? I'm still searching for the answer.... :-(